# Question in Stackoverflow about Wordpress,

Tags: discussion

Should I move [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905098/get-post-id-to-in-php) to this forum? And if so what is the right way to go about doing that?

Comment: This question should be asked in the "meta" site for this stack, not here, but yes. Be aware that third party plugins are off topic though.

Comment: even if its about using one to develop another?

Comment: No, I think its fine since you are creating plugins.

Comment: thanks... may repost here then...